# Writing massive kernel files for focal statistics in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, focal-statistics

I would like to run focal statistics on a raster and apply a weighted kernel file.
The issue is that I have a dense raster (and I would like to keep it this way for a reason) on the other hand I am interested in a vast focal area (eg. 1000 x 1000 px). I am about to write a kernel file to specify my weights and it seems completely crazy to type 10000000 digits into a notepad text file.

Am I missing something?

Is there any function or tool to create massive kernel txt files?

Is there a smarter way to get the same distance-weighted focal statistics result?

Comment: Possible using python but what are the weight values? You have a raster of them now?

Comment: I don't have a ready raster yet, I would like to use negative exponential function (decreasing weights with increasing distance)

Comment: Highest value at center of 1000*1000?

Comment: Yes,  highest  in the middle, lowest at the edges.